# SoftDelete records in Pivot table Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an issue with the soft deleting of records in a pivot table in my Laravel 5.4 application. In my Records.php I have a association with teams like:

```
public function teams()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class)
      ->withTimestamps();
}
```

When I update a record, I use the sync method to easily add/remove teams. The teams are selected in a multiple select form field and updated like:

```
$record->teams()->sync($request->get('teams'));
```

When adding new teams, the pivot table DOES update the created_at and updated_at. But when REMOVING a pivot table record, the whole row is deleted and the deleted_at is not set? How can I get the soft deleting to work in a pivot table.

Comment: Please provide you model details

Comment: May be it can help you..https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/soft-delete-pivot-records